# How can I script the deployment of a Visual Studio database project?

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, deployment, database-project

How can I script the deployment of a Visual Studio database project?

I have a DB project in visual studio and I would like to use it in order to deploy on remote machines via a script. I notice that when I 'deploy' from visual studio, it generates a .sql file.

I intercepted this file and tried running it from the command line with osql.exe, but I didn't have any success. Should this work, is there a better way to deploy a database programatically from a database project, may be by referencing in another project and calling some method to deploy it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
MSBuild /target:SQLBuild MyProjectName.dbproj
```

Performs a build-only action. It builds only a single database project named MyProjectName.dbproj. The project properties within the .dbproj file are used to assemble the build script.

```
MSBuild /target:Deploy /property:TargetDatabase=UpdatedTargetDatabase;TargetConnectionString="Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" MyProjectName.dbproj
```

Deploys the database project, overriding the target database name and connection string.

Comment: mine says that `The target "SQLBuild" does not exist in the project.` doesn't exist in the project. and it is my `.dbproj`

Answer (score 0):

For me in `Vs2010`, this one produced the file

`MSBuild /target:Deploy MyProjectName.dbproj`

another option is

`MSBuild /target:Build;Deploy MyProjectName.dbproj`

additional information found at
http://ishan-patel.blogspot.com/2012/04/create-single-database-deployment.html