# Automating Database Project Deployment

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2005, hudson, database-project

I'm using the method outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823890/how-can-i-script-the-deployment-of-a-visual-studio-database-project) to automate the database deploy with Hudson.  When I deploy the project from within Visual Studio, everything works fine and it updates the target database.  When it runs in Hudson, I get this warning: "Deploy warning TSD01266: The source's object [DBName] is different than the target's version of the object but the target object will not be updated." 
Has anyone else run into this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try google: I found following link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/408136ac-1940-403d-8027-1ceaeedc7b46

Answer (score 0):

Is it in both cases the same database? Can you run the commands from command line with the Hudson user?

Comment: I get the same error when I run the command while remoted into the machine.  It is the same database in both cases.

Comment: Have a look at this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/0826dd27-cec9-41ca-8f5f-779f4aadf916